# R - Select the best combinations of rows using nested list (Brute Forcing)

Tags: r, list, loops, combinations, lapply

I'm trying to generate all combinations of rows in my data frame in a nested list, fit and predict a linear model on every set, and select the best set (minimum error).

My data frame:

```r
    myFunction <- function (x) {
                  (x[2] - 5.1/(4 * pi^2) * (x[1] ^2) + 5/pi * x[1] - 6)^2 +
                  10 * (1 - 1/(8 * pi)) * cos(x[1] ) + 10
    }
    set.seed(1)
    x1 <- runif(5)*15-5
    x2 <- runif(5)*15
    y <- as.matrix(apply(cbind(x1,x2),1,myFunction))
    df <- data.frame(x1,x2,y)
```

I generate all the combinations of rows:

```r
    Mycomb <- function(elements, simplify = FALSE){
    result <- lapply(seq_along(elements), function(m)
    combn(elements, m, simplify = simplify))
  
    result
    }

    combinations <- Mycomb(1:5)

    sub_df_list <- lapply(combinations, function(inx_list)
    lapply(inx_list, function(i) df[c(1, i),])
    )

    >sub_df_list

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#          x1       x2        y
#1 -1.0173701 13.47585 47.79895
#2  0.5818585 14.17013 99.96885

#[[1]][[2]]
#        x1        x2        y
#1 -1.01737 13.475845 47.79895
#3  3.59280  9.911967 64.76098

#[[1]][[3]]
#         x1        x2        y
#1 -1.017370 13.475845 47.79895
#4  8.623117  9.436711 60.39821

#[[1]][[4]]
#         x1         x2        y
#1 -1.017370 13.4758453 47.79895
#5 -1.974771  0.9267941 82.26291


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#          x1        x2        y
#1 -1.0173701 13.475845 47.79895
#2  0.5818585 14.170129 99.96885
#3  3.5928005  9.911967 64.76098

#...
```

But I don't know how to apply fit and predict `lm` on every generated set to select which set produces the minimum error:

```r
    fit <- lm(y~x1+x2, sub_df_list)
    mytest <- data.frame(x1=1,x2=2) # test data is fixed
    pred <- predict(fit,mytest)
    real <- myFunction(c(1,2))
    sqrt((pred - real)^2) # calculates error
```

I don't really know how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the structure of `sub_df_list` important?

Comment: @LMc the structure of ```sub_df_list ```  is not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try the code below, where `sub_df_list` is obtained by `lapply` over `unlist(combinations, recursive = FALSE)`

```
sub_df_list <- lapply(unlist(combinations, recursive = FALSE), function(k) df[k, ])
```

and then compute the errors with respect to `real`

```
errors <- sapply(
  sub_df_list,
  function(v) abs(predict(lm(y ~ ., v), data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = 2)) - myFunction(c(1, 2)))
)
```

such that

```
        1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1 
 26.17132  78.34121  43.13334  38.77058  60.63527  91.98179  33.59375  28.80784
        1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
 46.44878  73.45175  76.28356  81.23705  45.38206  51.28394  54.49797 204.15358
        1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1
361.40750 158.85971 100.03526  61.93911  58.12593  21.52984  40.75905  51.79650
        1         1         1         1         1         1         1
 56.25079  69.51678  56.16817  54.03099  59.05836  49.33699  53.05278
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I replace ```lm(y ~ ., v)``` with ```glmnet(x,y)``` ?

Answer (score 0):

First I would flatten you `sub_df_list` so it is a simple list of data.frames. At the moment it is a list of lists (of data.frames).

```
datasets = unlist(sub_df_list, recursive=F)
```

After that, we want to run an `lm`  whose data argument changes everytime, to match the elements of `sub_df_list`. This can be done by using `lapply` with an anonymous function, much like you did to generate combinations.

```
models = lapply(datasets, function(dataset) { lm(y~x1+x2, data=dataset) })
```

from there on, the rest of your code should work. You just need to put it in a function and use lapply to use it on every element of your models list.